# npx create-react-app show error when installing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npx

npx create-react-app shoing eror whent installing, please help me how to solve this
problem. my nodejs version is v16.14.2 and npm version is 8.5.0

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1354 packages in 1m

171 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: instagram-clone@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/psn/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/psn/.npm/_logs/2022-04-12T07_12_21_032Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing- 
library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are running `npx create-react-app` command in a project that already includes react. Try running `npm install` instead.

If that does not work try to remove your node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Delete both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. Run `npm i web-vitals --save-dev`
3. Run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a project ( either next or react one ), and there is some similar type of error. try to reinstall npx with following command. That worked for me.

```
npm i -g npx
```